# Content fitting and re-sizing to a div container

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, height, autoresize

I am trying to make a page that is setup like the image.
A & B are dynamic heights, their widths are static. C is a static size height 500px and width 500px.

How do i make it so that the content height in each A & B resize each other without going over the height of say 500px

http://i47.tinypic.com/zvyd7d.png

Comment: Please post your relevant code and consider creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the CSS of a and b.

`max-height:500px;`.

As long as you are escaping your floats (if any) correctly, it will cut it off there.

You may need to add

`overflow:hidden;`

if your content in a or b extends 500px, this will cut it from being seen in the page.

The completed code as I understand the question is

The CSS

```
#wrap { width: 700px; height:500px; } /* this combines both static widths and height stays dynamic */
.a, .b { float:left; background-color:#F03; width: 200px; height:50%; min-height:100px; max-height: 500px; }
.c { background-color:#990; width: 500px; height: 500px; float: right; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

Notice the C is on top. That's because it floats to the right side of the container and the rest tries to find room that C isn't filling. Background colors just for visual aid.

**http://jsfiddle.net/QW5MQ/**  <-- These are your friend.

Comment: Yeah i tried this and variations like this.
I guess what better describes is that A is like a header of B and the header changes sizes based on How much text is in it. I need the Line between A & B to be pushed or pulled and the whole thing stays 500px high.

thank you for replying so quickly and helpfully

Comment: Other than the imaginary values (200px, min-height:100px), this code is exactly what you said you wanted. I used the image. A is a box on the top left. It is set at 200 width and a max of 500px, set to take up 50% of space just because the div is empty.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QW5MQ/1/ Modified further to look identical to image you provided.

Comment: I've tried this way. it provides the look. but it doesn't work the way im trying to make it work even if i try with javascript. I don't think its possible anymore. Thank you anyway.

Comment: if you're wanting A to expand over C, and B to fall below A, you could always position C absolutely to the bottom right, leave A with no floats, and B with left float. You could even wrap A in a width:100% container so it reserves the space. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're wanting. Good luck!

Comment: I shouldn't have included C, Doesn't really matter I don't have any issues with C, or the Whole wrapper, no issues with that.

The only issues i have are with A and B, A is a header of text and that is all. While B is an Iframe, i Need the top of B to pushed down right below A when the header of A drops down because the Header(A) is a variable and its size changes based on the number of characters in the header. And B(iframe) just has text inside.

A is the only only thing that changes size really.

Comment: yeah, the width of A isn't that important, I just worried about its Height and Bs height and they can't go over 500px. A is mostly always way smaller than B with like 2-3 sometimes 4 lines of text that. B is just an iframe and its contents don't effect the size of B, A should effect the Size of B because its pushing down on it and the bottom of B should stay static and stick to the wrapper and not go over.

Comment: Well.. it isn't recommended but you could use absolute positioning on all 3 elements.. `.a, .b, .c { position:absolute; }` `.a { top:0; left:0; }` `.b { bottom:0; left:0; }` `.c { bottom:0; right:0; }`. These will overflow each other if you aren't careful. You can stack order with `z-index:` in CSS.